# DOA+DELPHI Чем больше потоков, тем дольше SetVariable

Tags: многопоточность, oracle, delphi-xe

В каждом потоке свои OracleSession и свои OracleQuery. Выполняется один и тот же запрос. Меняются только значения. Переменные запроса массивы (PL/SQL Table).
Выполняю заполнение переменных **SetVariable**  в одном потоке - время 1 сек,
при 10 потоках 3 сек, при 20 10 сек и т.д. 
Если у меня все независимо, то почему растет время присвоения переменных?

Comment: Может, пример кода? Я совсем не спец по Oracle, но другие сервера БД более или менее благосклонны к мультипоточности, если не наглеть с их количеством

Comment: Скорее всего, я просто наглею с количеством ((

Comment: У меня часто программы при количестве модулей процессора > 6 используют число модулей - 2 потоков для запросов, плюс основной поток программы. Это не то, чтобы оптимальное число, но вполне проверенное временем для активной работы с БД + кое-какие расчёты.